# IIS Not working

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-applications

I have a web site that built on Visual studio 2008 and
i need to run it from my computer (Win 7 Ultimate)  as a server
I tried to publish it to IIS and this is simply not working
and i have the flowing error :

`Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

`Config Error This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".`
any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly problem but IIS never warn about it
i have missed installing the component (from control panel) that support ASP.NET 
when i installed it ,it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Web.config file contains some disallowed section. Some sections can only be set in the machine-wide configuration, some can only be set at the root of a web site, etc.

Simplify your web.config as much as possible (make it as empty as possible) and when the page displays, add one section at a time.